# Replace datetime value in GCS json file using sed

Tags: sed, google-cloud-storage

I need to replace the datetime value in a json file stored in GCS with date:
e.g. datetimestamp value **"2020-04-18 10:09:09.433000" should be replaced with 2020-04-18** strip out the timestamp part.

I have tried the following:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/cloudsql_to_bigquery/Accounts_test - \
| sed  -e's/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]*//g' \
| gsutil cp - gs://bucket/cloudsql_to_bigquery/Accounts_test
```

But I keep ending up with an application/octet file type instead of JSON not sure why also my sed isn't working as expected. Any clue how I can fix this?

Sample json file:

```
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20 06:37:29.630000", "_etblBudgets_iBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iChangeSetID": 1, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedAgentID": null, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedAgentID": 0, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedBranchID": 0, "dBudgetDTStamp": null, "fBudget": null, "fBudgetForeign": 0.0, "fForecast": 0.0, "fForecastForeign": 0.0, "fUnprocessedPOValue": -1768.0100000000002, "fUnprocessedPOValueForeign": 0.0, "iBudgetAccountID": 137, "iBudgetAccountType": 36, "iBudgetPeriodID": 12, "iBudgetProjectID": 7, "iBudgetTxBranchID": 0, "idBudgets": 1}
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20 06:37:29.630000", "_etblBudgets_iBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iChangeSetID": 1, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedAgentID": null, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedAgentID": 0, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedBranchID": 0, "dBudgetDTStamp": null, "fBudget": null, "fBudgetForeign": 0.0, "fForecast": 0.0, "fForecastForeign": 0.0, "fUnprocessedPOValue": -19238.68, "fUnprocessedPOValueForeign": 0.0, "iBudgetAccountID": 138, "iBudgetAccountType": 36, "iBudgetPeriodID": 12, "iBudgetProjectID": 7, "iBudgetTxBranchID": 0, "idBudgets": 2}
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20 06:37:29.630000", "_etblBudgets_iBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iChangeSetID": 1, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedAgentID": null, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedAgentID": 0, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedBranchID": 0, "dBudgetDTStamp": null, "fBudget": null, "fBudgetForeign": 0.0, "fForecast": 0.0, "fForecastForeign": 0.0, "fUnprocessedPOValue": -38647.87, "fUnprocessedPOValueForeign": 0.0, "iBudgetAccountID": 138, "iBudgetAccountType": 36, "iBudgetPeriodID": 12, "iBudgetProjectID": 8, "iBudgetTxBranchID": 0, "idBudgets": 3}
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20 06:37:29.630000", "_etblBudgets_iBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iChangeSetID": 1, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedAgentID": null, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedAgentID": 0, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedBranchID": 0, "dBudgetDTStamp": null, "fBudget": null, "fBudgetForeign": 0.0, "fForecast": 0.0, "fForecastForeign": 0.0, "fUnprocessedPOValue": 0.0, "fUnprocessedPOValueForeign": 0.0, "iBudgetAccountID": 138, "iBudgetAccountType": 36, "iBudgetPeriodID": 12, "iBudgetProjectID": 9, "iBudgetTxBranchID": 0, "idBudgets": 4}
```

Expected output:

```
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20", "_etblBudgets_iBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iChangeSetID": 1, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedAgentID": null, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedAgentID": 0, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedBranchID": 0, "dBudgetDTStamp": null, "fBudget": null, "fBudgetForeign": 0.0, "fForecast": 0.0, "fForecastForeign": 0.0, "fUnprocessedPOValue": -1768.0100000000002, "fUnprocessedPOValueForeign": 0.0, "iBudgetAccountID": 137, "iBudgetAccountType": 36, "iBudgetPeriodID": 12, "iBudgetProjectID": 7, "iBudgetTxBranchID": 0, "idBudgets": 1}
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20", "_etblBudgets_iBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iChangeSetID": 1, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedAgentID": null, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedAgentID": 0, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedBranchID": 0, "dBudgetDTStamp": null, "fBudget": null, "fBudgetForeign": 0.0, "fForecast": 0.0, "fForecastForeign": 0.0, "fUnprocessedPOValue": -19238.68, "fUnprocessedPOValueForeign": 0.0, "iBudgetAccountID": 138, "iBudgetAccountType": 36, "iBudgetPeriodID": 12, "iBudgetProjectID": 7, "iBudgetTxBranchID": 0, "idBudgets": 2}
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20", "_etblBudgets_iBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iChangeSetID": 1, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedAgentID": null, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedAgentID": 0, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedBranchID": 0, "dBudgetDTStamp": null, "fBudget": null, "fBudgetForeign": 0.0, "fForecast": 0.0, "fForecastForeign": 0.0, "fUnprocessedPOValue": -38647.87, "fUnprocessedPOValueForeign": 0.0, "iBudgetAccountID": 138, "iBudgetAccountType": 36, "iBudgetPeriodID": 12, "iBudgetProjectID": 8, "iBudgetTxBranchID": 0, "idBudgets": 3}
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20", "_etblBudgets_iBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iChangeSetID": 1, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedAgentID": null, "_etblBudgets_iCreatedBranchID": null, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedAgentID": 0, "_etblBudgets_iModifiedBranchID": 0, "dBudgetDTStamp": null, "fBudget": null, "fBudgetForeign": 0.0, "fForecast": 0.0, "fForecastForeign": 0.0, "fUnprocessedPOValue": 0.0, "fUnprocessedPOValueForeign": 0.0, "iBudgetAccountID": 138, "iBudgetAccountType": 36, "iBudgetPeriodID": 12, "iBudgetProjectID": 9, "iBudgetTxBranchID": 0, "idBudgets": 4}
```

Comment: I suggest to use `jq` for this job.

Comment: the sample data contains datetime similar to what I have in the question, that was just an example. Basically I need to convert all datetimestamp values to date ONLY, strip out the timestamp part.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. I recommend making the match regex as specific as possible, to avoid inadvertently matching something you didn't mean if the file ever gets data you didn't expect. Here's a more specific sed expression that would do it:

   sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) .*/\1/'
2. You can test that your sed expression works locally before trying to download/upload with it, e.g., running this pipeline from the shell:

   echo 2020-04-18 10:09:09.433000 | sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) .*/\1/'
3. I recommend against doing streaming uploads/downloads (gsutil cp with "-" as a source or dest argument) because that will not use checksum validation of the data (which could result in data corruption). So, use something like:

   gsutil cp gs://bucket/cloudsql_to_bigquery/Accounts_test /tmp/Accounts_test

   sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) .*/\1/' /tmp/Accounts_test > /tmp/Accounts_test_truncated_timestamps

   gsutil cp /tmp/Accounts_test_truncated_timestamps gs://bucket/cloudsql_to_bigquery/Accounts_test

   rm /tmp/Accounts_test_truncated_timestamps

Comment: unfortunately when I run that regex on a local file it replaces the datetime correctly but strips out the remaining json. So for the sample:
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20
{"_etblBudgets_Checksum": null, "_etblBudgets_dCreatedDate": null, "_etblBudgets_dModifiedDate": "2020-03-20

Comment: Ah, I should have tried on your sample file. Try this sed command instead:

sed -E 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) [0-9:.]*/\1/'